# How to wait until list of tasks are done using CompletableFuture ?

Tags: java, java-stream, completable-future

I am experimenting with CompletableFutures and hope someone could help turn head around. My algorithm below:

1. I have list of Articles.
2. I call REST API to get Categories for each Article.
3. I save Categories to DB.
4. I want perform steps 2 and 3 in parallel manner.

I want to wait until all Articles are processed, so there are no work done asynchronously after 2nd log.info().

My code is below:

```
    log.info("Starting CustomCommandLineRunner");

    List<Article> articles = articleService.getArticlesAvaialbleForAnalysis();

    List<CompletableFuture<Article>> futureArticlesList = articles.stream()
            .map(article -> {
                CompletableFuture<Map<String, Double>> futureCategoriesMap = categoryService.getArticleCategories(article.getUrl());
                return futureCategoriesMap.thenApply(categoriesMap -> articleService.setCatgoriesForArticle(article, categoriesMap));
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    CompletableFuture<Void> allArticlesFuture = CompletableFuture.allOf(futureArticlesList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futureArticlesList.size()]));
    allArticlesFuture.get();

    log.info("Ended CustomCommandLineRunner");
```

Unfortunately `articleService.setCatgoriesForArticle()` invoked twice. Could you please push me into right direction?

Comment: Have you tried using an ```ExecutorService```? Or have you tried working with ```CompletableFuture.isDone()```

Comment: As a side note, you can use the much simpler `CompletableFuture.allOf(futureArticlesList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]));`; specifying the size does not improve the performance, see [this great article on that topic](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/)…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize for false fire drill. Code in questions works as expected. `articleService.setCatgoriesForArticle()` is not invoked twice, but Spring `@Transactional` does not play well with CompletableFutures and this leads to issues with double save for same entity.

Lesson learned: do not mix `@Transactional` with asynchronous code.